How to use this multi view diagram to create a isometric diagram?
I just started out learning about isometric and multi view and am already confused. Can someone help create an isometric shape from this multi view diagram? Thank you.

Can someone help me? is not a question about creating an isometric diagram ... what is your question about the problem? ... please add it to your post

The question is asking you to visualise the part given the three views. i.e., What possible shape looks like that from the top, front and right side? Where are you stuck? Show your work so far.

The isometric picture at the top has no relationship to the orthographic projections shown below.

do you have any Lego bricks?

Have you tried to look for tutorials for this? It is pretty basic stuff in engineering. Look for axonometric projection https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNyVmjSug0k. Point on a plane gives you 2 out of 3 coordinates, so you usually need to combine information from 2 different views (e.g. top and front) to construct any other view.

Looks like you are a beginner and during the first lesson of the subject you were elsewhere or sleeped or played with your phone.
This resembles your drawing problem. The ortographic views of a three dimensional block are shown in the next image:

And one should construct the isometric view of the block.
To keep all simple for beginners the block has only X, Y and Z direction edges and the dimensions are multiples of 1 unit x 1 unit rectangular grid, so the block can be seen as a combination of equally sized cubes.
Isometric view  is a special projection where all X, Y and Z direction lines are seen with the same scaling. Drawing programs and some preprinted engineering drawing paper sheets have axonometric grid for equally spaced X, Y and Z direction lines. I used computer program Inkscape. Here's my result:

The skewed top, right and front views are not necessary, they are drawn drawn for you to help the understanding process. One should be able to draw the block directly after seeing the ortographic views. I colored the surfaces just for fun. The actual problem doesn't need colors, but colors can make the geometric form easier to be seen, when the colors present light variations.
A plain drawing paper is ok if one has the time and drawing tools to construct the grid angles (vertical and tilted from it plusminus 60 degrees). The grid itself is not a must. Many of us have surely constructed isometric drawings with a pen, a compass, a quite long straight ruler and a right angled triangle ruler which has 30 and 60 degrees sharp angles.
